# How to plot 2 surfaces and their intersection curve in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the equations of two surfaces and I want to plot both of them and highlight their intersection
My code looks like this

`t=linspace(-1,1,100);`

`x=t;`

`y=t;`

`z=cos(t.^8+12);`

`plot3(x,y,z,'g-','linewidth',3)`

`hold on`

`[x,y]=meshgrid(-2:2,-2:2);`
`surf(x,y,z)`

And that gives me the plot for the surface z = f(x,y) but I can not figure out how to plot the plane x=y

Comment: I was unable to get the surface plot running. Has something been omitted from the code posted? I'm also not sure what context is when using t when plotting in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Subject to editing upon further question details.

Here might be an interesting starting point. Below is a script that uses the `patch()` function to create the rectangle plane x = y. The patch function takes corner coordinates of a rectangle to plot in the 3D case (x,y,z) coordinates. Unfortunately, I was unable to get the surface plot from the above code. So the intersection discussion is a story for another time.

**Function Call:**

```
patch(X_Coordinates,Y_Coordinates,Z_Coordinates,Colour);
```

[image: Plotting XY-Plane and Line Function]

```
%***************************************************%
%3D line plot%
%***************************************************%

x = linspace(-1,1,100);
y = linspace(-1,1,100);
z = cos(x.^8+12);
plot3(x,y,z,'g-','linewidth',3)

%***************************************************%
%3D surface plot%
%***************************************************%

hold on
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:0.01:2,-2:0.01:2);
z = cos(x.^8+12);
% surf(x,y,z);

%***************************************************%
%Plotting the xy-plane%
%***************************************************%

Plane_Top = 255;
Plane_Bottom = -255;
Plane_Width = 4;

%Using plane attributes to set patch points%
X = [-Plane_Width/2 -Plane_Width/2 Plane_Width/2 Plane_Width/2];
Y = [-Plane_Width/2 -Plane_Width/2 Plane_Width/2 Plane_Width/2];
Z = [Plane_Bottom Plane_Top Plane_Top Plane_Bottom];

%Plotting characteristics%
Colour = [252/255 148/255 3/255];
patch(X,Y,Z,Colour);
view(3);
grid on;
xlabel("X-Axis"); ylabel("Y-Axis");
title("Plotting the XY-Plane and Line Function");
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**